# UDP Multicast error not receiving message

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, multicast

I can't receive message in multicast by my server however the sending is good I think, I supposed I messed with the IP's but don't know how to solve this.

Here is my testClient:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
socklen_t   groupSockLength;
int sd;
uint8_t databuf[5000] ;
int datalen = sizeof(databuf);
std::ofstream MyFile("TestAppliMsgReceive.txt");
ssize_t resRecv;


int main (int argc, char *argv[ ])
{
    /* Create a datagram socket on which to send. */
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
      perror("Opening datagram socket error");
      exit(1);
    }
    else
      std::cout<<"Opening the datagram socket...OK.\n"<<std::endl;

    /* Initialize the group sockaddr structure with a */

    /* group address of 225.1.1.1 and port 5555. */

    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));

    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.10.1.0");
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(50000);
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("10.16.2.1");

    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)

    {

      perror("Setting local interface error");

      exit(1);

    }

    else

      std::cout<<"Setting the local interface...OK\n"<<std::endl;

    

    /* Send a message to the multicast group specified by the*/

    /* groupSock sockaddr structure. */

    if(sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)

    {perror("Sending datagram message error");}

    else

      std::cout<<"Sending datagram message...OK\n"<<std::endl;

    while(1){
        std::cout<<"Which kind of message do you want to send?"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<" [1] Custom message "<<std::endl;;
        int choice;
        std::cin>>choice;
        if (choice==1) {
            std::cout<<"enter msg\n";
            std::cin>>databuf;
            datalen = sizeof(databuf);
            sendto(sd, databuf, datalen, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here the server side, Maybe the problem is more here than in the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>



//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Definition of variables common to all functions in the AppliMsg thread
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
static char         logInfoText[LOG_TEXT_SIZE]; // Text buffer for supervision log
static int          localSockDesc;              // Descriptor of the socket to the client application
static struct sockaddr_in   localSockAddr;      // IP address and port binded to the AppliMsg socket
static struct sockaddr_in   mcastSockAddr;      // Destination multicast address and port


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Init of AppliMsg thread
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void AppliMsgInit()
{
    std::string     stgNetCastAddr;     // Netcast IP address as a string
    std::string     stgNeighCastAddr;   // Neighbourcast IP address as a string
    std::string     stgLocalIpAddr;     // Ethernet interface IP address as a string
    uint16_t        localPortNum;           // Port number of the Ethernet interface
    struct ip_mreq  ipMcast;            // Multicast configuration
    unsigned int    numMcastTtl;        // TTL definition
    int             sockFlags;          // Flags of the socket


    
    // Destination multicast address and port
    mcastSockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    mcastSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("224.10.2.1");
    mcastSockAddr.sin_port=htons(50000);

    // Create the socket
    localSockDesc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // Configure the socket for multicast capability and non-blocking reception
    numMcastTtl = MCAST_TTL;
    setsockopt(localSockDesc , IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, (char *)&numMcastTtl, sizeof(numMcastTtl));
    sockFlags = fcntl(localSockDesc, F_GETFL);
    fcntl(localSockDesc, F_SETFL, sockFlags | O_NONBLOCK);

    // Bind the Ethernet interface IP address and port to the socket
    localSockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    localSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.16.2.1");
//    localSockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;         //SIMDEBUG
    localSockAddr.sin_port=htons(50000);

    // Bind the Ethernet IP address to the socket
    if (bind(localSockDesc,(struct sockaddr *) &localSockAddr,sizeof(localSockAddr)) < 0)
    {
        // Error case
     
    }

    // Subscribe to the multicast server
    ipMcast.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.10.2.1");
    ipMcast.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("10.16.2.1");
    setsockopt(localSockDesc, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&ipMcast, sizeof(ipMcast));

}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main function of the AppliMsg thread
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int AppliMsgWait()
{
    std::string     stgLocalIpAddr;
    std::string     stgNetCastAddr;     // Netcast IP address as a string
    std::string     stgNeighCastAddr;   // Neighbourcast IP address as a string
    struct ip_mreq  ipMcast;            // Multicast configuration


    // Main loop to process events from the simulated channel and the client application
    while (1)
    {
        // Check the update flag in the Configuration Context
        if (objConfigCtx.ConfigCtxGetFlagChangeAddr_()==true)
        {


            // Update the multicast configuration of the socket
            ipMcast.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.10.1.0");
            ipMcast.imr_interface.s_addr = inet_addr("10.16.2.1");

            setsockopt(localSockDesc, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&ipMcast, sizeof(ipMcast));
        }

        // Check the presence and receive of a message from the client application
        AppliMsgRecvSCOM();


        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }

    return 1;
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Check the presence and receive of a message from the client application
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void AppliMsgRecvSCOM()
{
    struct sockaddr_in  sourceSockAddr;             // Sender IP address
    socklen_t           sourceSockAddrLength;       // Temporary structure length
    stcDataTransmIndT   msgDataTransmInd;           // Structure of the internal message in the list
    ssize_t             resRecv;                    // Value returned by recv()


    sourceSockAddrLength = sizeof(sourceSockAddr);

    // Non-blocking receive for an application message sent by SCOM
    resRecv=recvfrom(localSockDesc,msgDataTransmInd.msgData,sizeof(msgDataTransmInd.msgData),0,
                        (struct sockaddr *) &sourceSockAddr,&sourceSockAddrLength);

    

    else if (resRecv > 0)
    {
        // An application message is received:

        
    }
}
```

And I think the focused part is about the IP address I used.

Comment: You're sending to `224.10.1.0;50000` but you're joining `224.10.2.1:50000`, and your comment says `225.1.1.1:5555`. Make up your mind.

Comment: Downvoted because this is not C code. Don't add wrong tags.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your reply , I dont get if there is a problem because even if I join on the same adress it doesnt work it only work when I have                                                   : ipmulticast.imrmultiadress.s_addr= 10.16.2.1 and ipmulticast.imr_intterface.s_addr=127.0.0.1

Comment: You should bind to INADDR_ANY unless you have a good reason that you understand for not doing so. I don't know what there is not to understand about my comment.